# Create product flavoured using android studio

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I want to create different product flavoured and I want to use main application code into created product flavoured.

I have created Two flavoured from [this link](https://objectpartners.com/2015/03/31/using-android-product-flavors-to-build-full-and-demo-version-of-the-app/) but I am not able to use my Main application code into created product flavoured.

I have mentioned package structured below and please let me know how can I use it.[image]

I have placed flavoured code inside src folder.

Thanks in advance,
And any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add build.gradle content?

Comment: Please show the entire project structure inside the src folder, as well as a short description of how you see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://antoniocappiello.com/2015/10/24/code-once-build-twice-product-flavours-at-rescue/) explains step by step how to configure your directory structure and gradle file.

The main steps are:

1. add the product flavours container to the app *build.gradle* file

   `productFlavors {
      free {
          applicationId "antoniocappiello.com.buildvariantsexample.free"
      }
      paid {
          applicationId "antoniocappiello.com.buildvariantsexample.paid"
      }
   }`
2. create inside src a directory with the exact name of the product flavour that you want to look different from the main variant, for example with the configuration at step 1 the directory name could be *paid* or *free*

[Directory structure example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39yHE.png)